# Kendo UI Angular - How do I Wrap Header Columns?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-ui-grid-ph71bj

I have no luck scouring Kendo UI's guides for a way to wrap the header text.
The only way I've seen is to set Angular Component's ViewEncapsulation to None, but I can't do the within the project I'm working on, there should be a better way to override it in the CSS but I can't figure out how.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?  I've included a Stackblitz with some sample data if anyone can figure it out.  It would be a giant help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the headerStyle input ([documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/api/ColumnComponent/#toc-headerstyle)) so that white-space is pre-wrap:

```html
<kendo-grid-column field="Category.CategoryName" title="Test Category Field" [headerStyle]="{'white-space': 'pre-wrap'}"></kendo-grid-column>
```

Fiddle: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-ui-grid-yhreaf